# Ajax with partial pages

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have partial `selectProduct.php`

```
`<?php
$data = $query->getProductType();
var_dump($data);
$objectMap = new ObjectMap($data);
$productTypeArray = $objectMap->dataToProductType();
?>

<select name="productType" id="productType" onchange="changeAttributeForm(this)">
    <option value="0">--Select product--</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($productTypeArray as $productType) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?= $productType->getProductID() ?>" id="<?= $productType->getProductTypeName() ?>">
            <?php echo $productType->getProductTypeName() ?>
        </option>

    <?php

    } ?>
</select>`
```

and 2nd partial `attributeForm.php`:

```
  <?php
echo $productTypeArray[0];
?>
```

I use this two partials in another page `form.php`:

```
<div>
<form id="#product_form">
    <label for="sku">SKU: </label>
    <input type="text" name="sku" id="sku"><br>
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <label for="price">Price: </label>
    <input type="text" name="price" id="price"><br>
    <label for="productType">Type switcher</label>
    <?php include "partial/selectProduct.php";
    ?>
    <div id="attribute"><?php
                        include "partial/attributeForm.php"; ?> </div>

</form>
```

When I use this 2 partials in `form.php` without ajax, it works perfectly. But when I use ajax:

```
`window.onload = function()
{
    loadAttributes(0);
}

function loadAttributes(productTypeId)
{
    var xhr =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function()
    {
        if(this.status==200 && this.readyState==4)
        {
           document.getElementById("attribute").innerHTML = this.responseText; 
           
        }

    }

    xhr.open("GET","partial/attributeForm.php?productTypeId="+productTypeId);
    xhr.send();

}

function changeAttributeForm(e)
{
    loadAttributes(e.value);
}
`
```

it gives me error `Undefied variable productTypeArray in attributeForm.php`. Via
`var_dump($productTypeArray)` I noticed that when I reload page, `$productTypeArray` is actually there for 0.03 seconds and then it disappear.
Anyone know why?

EDIT: after I read comments I tried to create this missing object directly in my `ajax` file:

```
 <?php
include "database/DBConnection.php";
include "database/Query.php";
include "classes/ProductType.php";
include "classes/ObjectMap.php";
$connection = new DbConnection();
$query = new Query($connection->getConnection());
$data = $query->getProductType();
var_dump($data);
$objectMap = new ObjectMap($data);
$productTypeArray = $objectMap->dataToProductType();
var_dump($productTypeArray)?>
```

but for every `include` line of code I get 2 warnings:

```
Warning: include(database/DBConnection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\partial\attributeForm.php on line 2
```

and

```
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'database/DBConnection.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\partial\attributeForm.php on line 2
```

Comment: Of course the variable does not exist, when you call `attributeForm.php` on its own. _"I noticed that when I reload page, $productTypeArray is actually there for 0.03 seconds and then it disappear."_ - because your PHP code initially output the correct data - and then you are making your faulty AJAX request, and _replace_ it with the faulty result that received.

Comment: And how to fix it?

Comment: Well if you want to output data that is supposed to be read from the database, then you need to actually make the database query first.

Comment: I tried to include files needed for creating these objects and create them in my ajax file, but I get error `failed to open stream, no such file`

Comment: We can't help you based on such overly vague verbal descriptions. Edit your question to show what exactly you did.

Comment: So your file system paths are simply wrong. If the script you are using this in is `partial/attributeForm.php`, then `include "database/DBConnection.php"` would mean it looks for `partial/database/DBConnection.php` now - is that where that file is actually located? This is _really_ stuff you should be able to figure out on your own, focus a bit more.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to add `../` to get out of current folder. Sorry and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use include, it includes that file in the middle of the one it was included in.

When you load a PHP file through AJAX it loads only that one file because you just opened it directly. It has no context of variables that were set in another file.

Comment: So, how to correct it?

Comment: The php file you are loading using ajax must define productTypeArray and give it content. Otherwise you just call a variable that does not exist there. 

Whatever you have at the beginning of selectProduct.php must also be in the ajax file you are trying to load, along with all the framework stuff that makes that data query work. 

Loading file through ajax is like opening index.php through browser every time. It's a standalone little page.

Comment: I already tried that, and I can't open stream `include "Query.php"`, or any other class that I need to create these objects, because: "No such file or directory"

Comment: Make sure all the paths to the files you include in ajax loaded file are in the right location relative to it, not the main index.php. The file that you load becomes the root file at that time and you have to point to files from it's starting position. For example, if you have ajax files in different folder, then you have to use relative path one step up from than folder, and only then to the target file. (../file_name.php)